# Installing 18.04 on ASUS GL552VW (-CN108T)

Tags: boot, nvidia, uefi, 18.04

I am trying to install 18.04 on an ASUS GL552VW, but I am experiencing one after another problem, and after spending the entire day of testing I am fed up with Ubuntu.

I'm hoping for a miracle to salvage this wreck before I reinstall Windows 10 and sell it. It is ridiculous that this configuration is having issues since it got released back in '15. I came from 16.04 (LM18.3) and it ran badly because the only working parameters were and are `noacpi acpi=off` and `noapic`.

The device is a GTX960M i7-6700HQ with integrated HD graphics 530.

For my latest attempt I followed this guide: [Installing Ubuntu in latest Asus Rog PCs](http://pclub.in/2017/01/06/Linux-on-Asus-ROG.html)

After completion it is impossible to reboot successfully. Every time the screen goes black after a reboot. After I shutdown and then boot, the system boots with a display but the keyboard backlight and touchpad are both not working.

After trying parameters like these:

> nomodeset nv nvidia.modeset=0 i915.modeset=0 nouveau.modeset=0 acpi=off noacpi noapic nosplash idle=nomwait rdblacklist=nouveau nouveau.runmp=0

I enabled the proposed package for beta support, but still had no luck.

All of these parameters gave different outputs and addressed new issues, and some did not even let me pass grub without failing.

I have tried nvidia-361 -340 -384 and -390, and although I tried the various versions all came with 390 dependencies installed.

I am at this point completely lost because I can't think of any option worth trying.

Comment: What happens if you boot to the liveUSB? Does that work?

Comment: booting usb works with adding nouveau.modeset=0

Comment: I would boot from the usb and do a full reinstall (easy way) or you can use the liveUSB to chroot and finish the upgrade (educational) instructions in this post:https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1863385

Comment: I managed to got to the grub menu by waiting till the ASUS Splash logo got away.  Took about 5 seconds.  In the upper left corner appears a line of text; "Booting into insecure mode" at that point press Esc to go to grub menu. This took me a few attempts. To early and BIOS boot menu shows and to late GRUB commandline shows. By removing the parameters "ro quiet splash $vt_handoff ---" and inserting nouveau.modeset=0  the system booted. Installed Nvidia, updated Grub and rebooted and now it boots with video. Will take some time to get everything working.  I see there are some errors to fix.

Comment: That's great you got it working! You should post your answer here!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `nouveau-modeset=0`, you can use `nvidia.modeset=0` for a pure Intel HD 530 graphics environment which is many times easier to use than nVidia.

Many users find less screen-tearing and crisper fonts with Intel. Additionally there is less power drain and heat.

After installation and successful booting into Ubuntu you can type into the terminal:

```
sudo prime-select intel # turn on intel graphics
```

or:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia # turn on nvidia graphics
```

Then reboot to implement the configuration change.

Note you don't type `#` and the comment that follows.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The author's solution copied from a comment below the question:

> I managed to got to the GRUB menu by waiting until the ASUS splash screen logo disappeared. It took about 5 seconds. In the upper left corner appears a line of text: `Booting into insecure mode` – at that point press Esc to go to the GRUB menu. This took me a few attempts. Too early and the BIOS boot menu shows, and too late the GRUB command-line shows. By removing the parameters `ro quiet splash $vt_handoff ---` and inserting `nouveau.modeset=0` the system booted. I installed the Nvidia driver, updated grub and rebooted, and now it boots to graphics mode. It will take some time to get everything working. I see there are some errors to fix.

It also works on ASUS XZ553VD.